# while loop not exiting when value met

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop, coded-ui-tests

I have a scenario where I want to check the value of a cell in an application. When the value of the cell hits 0 or -1 I'd like the test to continue. So I have:

```
while (!cell.Value.Equals("0") || !cell.Value.Equals("-1")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value ({1})",cell_value.Value);
    Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
```

Unfortunately, when the cell reaches 0, it doesn't appear to 'break' out of the loop.

```
Output:
    Value (20)
    Value (13)
    Value (10)
    Value (9)
    Value (4)
    Value (1)
    Value (0)
    Value (0)
    Value (0)
    Value (0)
```

Is it best to try this with a while / do + while loop or is a for loop better?

Thanks,

J.

Comment: Your boolean expression will always be true - i.e. there is no string that is both "0" and "-1" which would cause it to be false.

Comment: Am i not saying, if my cell is not 0 or my cell is not -1 then sleep for 15 seconds.. so 20, 13, 10 etc are not 0 or -1, so keep waiting until the cell is 0 or -1.

Comment: Or like wise if cell.equals 0 or -1 then break.. but then it just does it once, so I'd want it to loop and keep checking, so a for loop checking x amount of times, but I don't want to limit the loop to the value of x as it can take some time to hit 0 or -1

Comment: John, your loop explicitly says `while string is not "0" OR is not "-1"` - that is always true. Please check the answers provided here for the correct implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` means that at least one must be true. Therefore when you enter 0 what you get is:

1. `!cell.Value.Equals("0")` - "not true" = `false`
2. `!cell.Value.Equals("-1")` - "not false" = `true`

and therefore it enters. You want to be using `&&` instead:

```
while (!cell.Value.Equals("0") && !cell.Value.Equals("-1"))
```

Or write it like this:

```
// while not (equals 0 or -1)
while (!( cell.Value.Equals("0") || cell.Value.Equals("-1")))
```

Comment: 0 or -1 is an acceptable value to break out of the loop.. as it counts down to 0 if its 3 for example and a value of -5 comes in it going to -1 by default..

Comment: while (!( cell.Value.Equals("0") || cell.Value.Equals("-1"))) is a hit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your condition should probably be:

```
while (!cell.Value.Equals("0") && !cell.Value.Equals("-1"))
```

As it is currently written, at least one of the sides will be true (any string is always either NOT "0" **OR** NOT "-1").