# Cant get while loop to check if my userinput equals some numbers

Tags: c#, loops

This is the piece of code I am talking about. So I want the user only to be able to write 1 or 2 or else the while loop will never break. The problem is that for some reason the loop just never breaks, even if I write 1 or 2.

```
while (caseSwitch != 1 || caseSwitch != 2)
{
    Console.Write("Please write a number: ");
    Int32.TryParse(userInput = Console.ReadLine(), out caseSwitch);
}
```

Comment: Beacuse `caseSwitch`  it is always  unequal 1 OR unequal 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [while loop not exiting when value met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038533/while-loop-not-exiting-when-value-met)

Answer (score 2):

`caseSwitch` has an any time only a single value so it will always be either not 1 or not 2. Replace `||` with `&&`. Meaning you loop as long as `caseSwitch` is not 1 and is not 2. The moment it is one of them it halts.

```
while (caseSwitch != 1 && caseSwitch != 2)
{
    Console.Write("Please write a number: ");
    Int32.TryParse(userInput = Console.ReadLine(), out caseSwitch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: there is another solution to this problem using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
while (!(caseSwitch == 1 || caseSwitch == 2))
{
     Console.Write("Please write a number: ");
     Int32.TryParse(userInput = Console.ReadLine(), out caseSwitch);
}
```